# How do I get file size in megabytes using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a function that will validate the size. See code below:

```
    var filename = $(this).get(0).files; //e.g. 2MB
    var maxFileSize = 10; //in megabytes (MB)
    IsFileSizeValid(file, maxFileSize); //returns true or false

    //Check file size is valid 
    function IsFileSizeValid(filename, maxFileSize) {
        /*TODO*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).get(0).files[0].size` - get first file size in bytes
`$(this).get(0).files[0].size/1048576` - in MiB, `1048576` is `2^20` or `1024^2`